# Inputting an array in a function pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a unified function for a PDO prepare UPDATE statement. But I am doing something wrong. Help would be very much appreciated.

I'm passing an array and an email to a function:

```
function refreshUserData($items,$email)
{
    global $pdo;

    $keys = array_keys($items);
    $keys = '('. implode(",", $keys) . ')';

    $values = array_values($items);
    $values = '(\''. implode("','", $values) . '\')';

    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET $keys VALUES $values WHERE email=?");
    $query->bindValue(1,$email);
    $query->execute();
}
```

But I am doing something wrong because when I try to run a function `Uncaught exception`

This is my first attempt at doing this so don't know what to do.

Array being passed through:

```
Array ( [google_id] => 11111111111111 [emal] => email@gmail.com [first_name] => First [last_name] => Last [profile_url] => https://plus.google.com/+FirstLast )
```

And after implodes:

```
(google_id,emal,first_name,last_name,profile_url)

('11111111111111','email@gmail.com','First','Last','https://plus.google.com/+FirstLast')
```

Comment: can you give us an example array that is being passed in for the $items variable?

Comment: **Off-topic**: Please do not use `global`! Abstract your functionality into a class and inject the PDO-handle (or just pass it to the function), but referencing a dependency from out of nowhere is almost always bad practice.

Comment: Oh, and concerning your problem: You have to wrap your values in single quotes:  `$values = "('". implode("','", $values) . "')";`

Comment: @Quasdunk After altering the code for the values: `$values = '(\''. implode("','", $values) . '\')';`  still not working

Comment: Is there any error description? Or could you catch the error and echo out the message? The problem might be the misspelled `email`-field. Also, if it's not from copy-pasting, there are quotes missing between *First* and *Last* in the imploded value-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax
UPDATE syntax is always like:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columname = 'value', othercolumn = 'othervalue'
```